# Dynamodb query with date range issue in python boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB table, I need to find the records which are between the given date range.
So here is my table structure

```
{
"Id":"String",
"Name":"String",
"CrawledAt":"String"
}
```

In this table partition key as Id and CrawledAt fileds used. And also created local secondary index with CrawledAt field and it's name "CrawledAt-index"

When querying most of the articles using Id with CreatedAt. But in my case I don't know what is the Id, I only need to retrieve records for a particular date range.

Here is the code I have tried

```
request = {
                 "TableName": "sflnd00001-test",
    "IndexName": "CrawledAt-index",
    "ConsistentRead": False,
    "ProjectionExpression": "Name",
    "KeyConditionExpression": 
        "CrawledAt between :v_start and :v_end",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v_start": {"S": "2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"},
        ":v_end": {"S": "2025-11-31T00:00:00.000Z"} }
        }
          
        response = table.query(**request)
```

It's returning this error

```
"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: BETWEEN, operand type: M",
```

Can someone please tell me how to find data set with the given date range without providing primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a `between` or any other function on a partition key, you must always provide the entire key.

For your use-case your GSI partition key should be a single value, and the `crawledAt` should be the sort key.

```
{
"Id":"String",
"Name":"String",
"CrawledAt":"String",
"GsiPk": "Number"
}
```

.

```
"KeyConditionExpression": 
            "GsiPk = 1 AND CrawledAt between :v_start and :v_end"
```

This would then allow you to retrieve all the data in the table between two dates. But be aware of the caveat of doing this, using a single value for a GSIPK is not scalable, and would cap the write requests to approx 1000WCU.

If you need more scale you can assign a random number to the GSIPK (n) to increase the number of partitions which would then require you to make (n) queries to collect all the data.

Alternatively you can `Scan` the table and use `FilterExpression` which is also not a scalable solution:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name MusicCollection \
    --filter-expression "timestamp between :a and :b" \
    --expression-attribute-names file://expression-attribute-names.json \
    --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What did you mean by GsiPk = 1?
And I need to know, is this table structure wrong?

Comment: You need to add a new column to your data, which has a single value, I used 1 for an example. Then create a GSI based on that.

Comment: Be mindful of the scale you need, a single value could lead to issues and I mention that you may need to use random values in a given range to ensure you can scale if needed beyond 1000WCU.

Comment: If I use random value, then how I add them when doing query? because I don't know the value

Comment: If you use random between (0-4) then everytime you query you would need to issue 5 queries to ensure you get each key.

Comment: In my case I created this table to store meetings data. So I need to find meetings in a particular date range, For this scenario to this table structure is wrong?

Comment: You are trying to retrieve data sorted in a given way (between) based on multiple partition keys which is not possible without adding a GSI like I described above. Do you expect to consume more than 1000WCU per second?

Comment: At the moment no. But may be in the future. But I'm confusing with this GsiPk filed. So it's adding only for the querying, it doesn't contain a business perspective value

Comment: And another thing is my local secondary index is useless right in this case? I added it because I need to update this CrawledAt field. If I  put it without local secondary index, then I can;t update it

Comment: GsiPk is only used as a component to fulfil your read requirements, i.e get all data between x and y.... 

As for the LSI, you cannot modify any item in an index, you must always update items on the base table, so yes, it seems your LSI is useless in this case as you need a GSI which will allow you to use a different partition key whereas an LSI won't.

Comment: Could you please explain this? " you cannot modify any item in an index, you must always update items on the base table" . In here what did you meant item in an index?
So isn't that index item also an item on the base table?

Comment: It is, but what I am saying is that you cannot directly modify an index, only the base table items which replicates to the indexes. You mention "I added it because I need to update this CrawledAt field", which does not make sense, unless you mean that you did not want to add that as a key on your base table as it would require a delete and put.

Comment: ok. Then can't we do this without adding GsiPk and with a Global secondary Index?

Comment: No, unless you want to use a `Scan` with a `FilterExpression` which would result in you reading your entire dataset to retrieve only a subset.